# detect realtime browser size and display UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, modernizr

I've designed a page which uses modernizr to detect the device based on the width.
The problem is that if i resize browser window the UI become bad. i want to make UI such a flexible that if i resize browser window, it should apppear it properly and if window width will be resized to 320px, browser will dispaly jquery-mobile ui.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Social Search</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.15317.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-title="Social Search" data-theme="b">
            <header data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Social Media Search</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="wrapper" data-role="content">
                <form id="frmSearch" action="#" method="POST">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="txtSearch">Search:</label>
                        <input type="search" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" required />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Go" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <footer data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
                <p>Powered by my company</p>
            </footer> 
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Modernizr.load([
                {
                    test: Modernizr.mq('(min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 728px)'),
                    yep : ['mob.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js'],
                    nope : 'pc.css'
                }
            ]);

            if (!Modernizr.borderradius) {
                $.getScript("jquery.corner.js", function () {
                    $("input").corner();
                });
            }

            if(!Modernizr.required) {
                $("#frmSearch").submit(function(){
                    if($.trim($("#txtSearch").val().length) == 0){
                        alert('Please, Enter some keyword');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            $(window).resize(function(){
                if($(window).width() 

            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a google for 'responsive design' and 'CSS media queries'. The approach you have here seems rather convoluted.

Comment: i've tried css medai queries but it's not working. i think `$(window).resize(function(){})` would work. but use of modernizr is compulsary. how can i put device-width logic using modernizr into resize() ?

Comment: Can't you just call the modernizr function from within your onresize handler?

Comment: `$(window).resize(function() {   
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    Modernizr.load([
     {
test: Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 728px)'),
yep : ['mob.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js'],
      nope : 'pc.css'
     }
    ]);
   });` this code not working properly